# gwtp HorizontalPanel verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE"

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Please find uibinder code below :

But, the button is not aligned properly in browser. but it is showing properly in eclipse designer.

Please help me to solve this.

```
<g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="a" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER" verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE">
        <g:Button width="150px" height="30px" ui:field="button">Click ThisThis</g:Button>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Thanks,
Bennet

Answer (score 4):

Wrap any children of a DockPanel, HorizontalPanel, or VerticalPanel that you need to set alignment on in a  element.

```
<g:HorizontalPanel>
    <g:cell width="800px" horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_RIGHT">
        <g:Button ui:field="closeButton" text="Close" />
    </g:cell>
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Have a look to this [link](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CellPanel.html).